# Need suggestions on designing artist recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following scenario.I need to recommend artists to users. How should this be modeled? I am looking for suggestions on this.

I was thinking. Based on following criterias:

1. When a user listens to a song, the songs genre gets recorded somewhere with +1
2. When a user "likes" a song, the songs genre gets recorded somewhere with +2

This way I could list all artists based on the genre that has the highest points.

Even still, should I have a new model called "Recommendation" and have it embedded into user?

I am open to all kinds of suggestions.

Comment: You should recommend artists based on the genre, but just remove the artists that the user didn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A User could have many Votes.  A Vote could be an up-vote or down-vote (using single table inheritance). You could then have a Recommendation model that determines what a user might like depending on up and down-votes (find related artists from up-votes and subtract artists related to down-votes.) A User then could have many Recommendations.

Comment: Hmmm... You are suggesting I recommend artists who have the higher votes to users? All this is doing is recommending "popular" artists though. What about based on genre?