# How come many startups used MySQL or PostgreSQL rather than MongoDB when they began?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, postgresql, database

How come many startups used MySQL or PostgreSQL rather than MongoDB when they started? Many of them seem to migrate to MongoDB later - why's that? Does it need a lot more effort in working with MongoDB? Why don't they just jump straight into MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB isn't fully comparable to a relational database like MySQL or PostGres - bear that in mind.  You're comparing apples and pineapples.

Comment: For one, MongoDB didn't exist when the startups I worked for started up (2007, 2008). At those places, the traditional relational model was a better fit for their data anyway, so they still won't be migrating to NoSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote User Dan Grossman:

You dumped a decades-tested, fully featured RDBMS for a young, beta-quality, feature-thin document store with little community support. Unless you're already running tens of thousands of dollars a month in servers and think MongoDB was a better fit for the nature of your data, you probably wasted a lot of time for negative benefit. MongoDB is fun to toy with, and I've built a few apps using it myself for that reason, but **it's almost never a better choice than Postgres/MySQL/SQL Server/etc**. for production applications.

[Mongodb and PostgreSql thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426540/mongodb-and-postgresql-thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB isn't SQL based nor is it relational which takes it out of the comfort zone of most developers and out of the common lingo of most CEOs. There are enough options that don't require re-inventing the development wheel and dealing with the learning curve of a different technology.

Also the first public release was in 2009, so you're still talking about a fairly new platform and people are going to be hesitant to use it. Not to mention the experienced developer base isn't as wide as for a SQL based DB.