# How to store big data for use in computation?

Tags: bigdata

I have recently started working on big data. Specifically, I have several GBs of data and I have to do computation (addition, modification) on it frequently. Since any computation on the data takes a lot of time, I been thinking of how to store the data for quick computation. Following are the options I have looked into:

1. **Plain text file**: The only advantage of this technique is inserting data is very easy. Changes to existing data are pretty slow, since there is no way to search for records efficiently.
2. **Database**: Insertion and modification of data are simplified. However, since this is a ongoing research project, schema may need to be updated frequently depending upon experimental results (this has NOT happened uptil now, but will definitely be something that may happen in near future). Besides, moving data around is not simple (as compared to a simple files). Moreover, I have noticed that querying data is not that quick as compared to when data is stored in XML.
3. **XML**: Using BeautifulSoup, only loading the XML file containing all the data takes around ~15 minutes and takes up ~15GB of RAM. Since it is quite normal to run scripts multiple times in a day, ~15 minutes for every invocation seems awfully long. The advantage is once the data is loaded, I can search/modify elements (tags) fairly quickly.
4. **JSON and YAML**: I have not looked into it deeply. They can surely compress the disk space needed to store the file (relative to XML). However, I have found no way to query records when data is stored in these formats (unlike database or XML).

What do you suggest I do? Do you have any other option in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a flexible database for a large amount of data, **MongoDB** may be the technology you are looking for.

MongoDB belongs to the family of the NoSQL database systems and is:

- based on JSON-alike documents
- highly performant even with large amounts of data
- schema-free
- document-based
- open-source
- queryable
- indexable

It allows you to modify your schema in the future in a very flexible way, quite easy to insert data (1.), modify the data and its structure (2.), faster than XML (3.) and JSON-based for efficient storage (4.).

Comment: But the selected answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426540/mongodb-and-postgresql-thoughts says "it's [MongoDB is] almost never a better choice than Postgres/MySQL/SQL Server/etc".

Comment: @Waqar: The selected answer is also 3 years old ;-) And you mentioned that your schema would change. My opinion is that MongoDB is now a lot further than where it was in 2010. But that's of course my opinion only.

Answer (score -1):

size of integer is 4,long long int is 8 byte and it can access about 19 digits data and for unsinged long long int size also 8 byte but handle larger value than long long int but this is less than 20 digits.Is there any way that can hangle over 20 digits data.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a>789456123789456123123)//want to take a higher thand this digits
    {
        cout<<"a is larger and big data"<<endl;
    }
}
```

I searched about it for a while but didn't find helpful contents.all about is java biginteger..